# Error with query with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying this:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT Users.*, Posts.* 
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN Posts ON Users.User = Posts.User 
WHERE MATCH (Posts.City) AGAINST ('$city2') 
ORDER BY Posts.`Date` DESC LIMIT 10");

if(!$result) {
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

I'm not getting an error but I'm getting zero results.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, in fact I think I didn't change anything and it was working before. I believe that adding quotes or something could fix the issue but I'm not sure what to do. A simpler query to select only from posts without the inner join works perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you do `mysql_real_escape_string($city2)`?

Comment: Show `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/mysql_query) more than once. Try changing your `if` statement to this:

```
if(!$result) {
```

Also, I hope nobody lives in a city with an apostrophe!

Comment: Ooops, somebody [definitely lives](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/US_cities_with_apostrophe)

Comment: Thanks. I changed it but I'm getting no results... is there a possible reason for this? If I remove the inner join an select only from posts I get results, but I need to do the inner join to get the user's avatar.

Comment: what happens if somebody lives in a city with an apostrophe? just curious

Comment: @Liso22: Say someone lives in Lee's Summit (thanks, J0HN). You'll end up with a query like this: `...AGAINST ('Lee's Summit')...` That's invalid SQL.

Comment: @Liso22: If you don't modify your code, it's vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_injection). You can escape the apostrophes using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Comment: I'm escaping it beforehand. I'm getting no results thought. I have no idea why, I didn't modify the code. Could there be a problem with the db I don't know why I don't get results

Comment: @Liso22: Okay; I just worry about SQL injection whenever I see a PHP string interpolation in an SQL query. Unfortunately, I don't know why you're not getting any results. Perhaps try your query from the command line (with the `mysql` command) and see if it works then. If not, it's a PHP problem, come back here. If it doesn't work on the command line, it's an SQL problem; ask a new question.